# how to copy big amount of small files in high performance?

Tags: c#, performance, copy

In my case, I call `file.copy()` to copy those small files (3KB) from different directories to different directories each. I put the source paths in a `list<string>`.

What can I do to improve the performance of copying? 
Should I use multi-thread? On just the sequential way?

Comment: In this case the bottle neck is harddisk I/O, not CPU, so multithreading won't help

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I found this link http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf - But I'm still not sure what to do. I have around 2 Mio of Files (fast growing) on NTFS and half of them are below 10KB and so I have the same problem if I want to copy them all...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could force performance into the issue as copying files is handled by Windows and you will be pretty much limited by the hardware that you have, e.g., the type of storage you are using (disk or SSD), the type of connection you have (LAN/USB 2.0 or 3.0/etc).

That being said an asynchronous file copy would probably work best for what you want to do whatever the scenario is. The best resource for that would be the [Asynchronous File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference on MSDN.

Comment: What advantage would doing asynchronous file I/O have in this case?

Comment: @Gabe Not locking up the UI thread, for instance, and allowing for non-modal progress reporting while the files are getting copied.

Comment: The question is about small files. Async is absolutely helpful for large files but in this case the overhead of wrapping each operation that will complete quickly adds up. The smaller the file, the less sense async makes. It will lower performance. Sync methods always outperform async.

Answer (score 0):

"`C# how to copy **big amount of small files in high performance**?`".

There is not much code in your question, so i am giving you a direction(help url) towards solution..

I would recommended using `Zipping` as an option. Advantages i feel..

1. Compression of the size.
2. Files are reduced to single zip file.

Because of above n/w copying get faster...

`NOTE` : For .Net 4.5 you can go ahead and use the `ZipFile`, prior to that you might need to use `GZip or Deflate` compression algorithms

MSDN url - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There may be some advantage to reading them into memory in large chunks (say, 1GB at a time) and then writing them out. This could allow them to be written to disk sequentially without having to move the disk heads back and forth so much.

Also consider using the more flexible `CopyFileEx` API as described [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=854). It allows you to specify `NoBuffering` to avoid filling up your cache with files you don't care about, plus offers asynchronous modes, cancellation, and progress reporting.

Answer (score -1):

I think You should copy file **Asynchronously**. Please find the below link that will help you to make an Asynchronous call for copying file.

[Asynchronous Programming Techniques](http://parassanghani.blogspot.in/2010/08/asynchronous-programming-techniques.html)

Comment: I don't see how this helps performance. Your link simply shows how to start a long-running task as a background thread, not how to make anything go faster.

Comment: the link shows how to use Asynchronous. And as suggested you can do Asynchronous task for copying file.

Comment: That link just shows a complicated way to run things in a background thread, which presumably the OP already knows about because threading is mentioned in the question. It does not show how to make asynchronous calls (`ReadAsync`, `WriteAsync`, `CopyToAsync`). It also has nothing to do with file copying or improving performance.